# Angular js Controller method from HTML with a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Could someone please help me in dealing the below situation.

I have an accordion, on click of accordion it expands.

Depending on header clicked I would like to load the data, or even preload the data.

I have a function in controller with below signature

```
$scope.getDetailsFn = function(Id){
    $scope.Details = "I am possible"
};
```

Accordion is as follows

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" >
   <uib-accordion-group heading="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in xs" >
      //Is the below possible or calling the below on ng-click possible
      {{getDetailsFn({{x.id}})}}
      {{Details}}
      Message: {{x.message}}
      </br>
   </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, looks like you want to display the data on click of the header? Just do this

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime" >
 <uib-accordion-group heading="{{x.id}}" ng-repeat="x in xs" ng-click="getDetailsFn(x.id)">
  {{Details}}
  Message: {{x.message}}
  </br>
 </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

And in the controller you would get 'x', so show the details based on x.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Did not know I can directly refer as x.id without {{ }}.